# Read JSON from dataFrame column with variable Schema

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe having one colum containing some nested JSON and also of variable schema.i.e. JSON in each row is having different schema.

For eg

```
Key     Value
1       {"foo":"bar"}
2       {"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}
```

I need to parse this and create a final dataframe which contains all the colums as per JSON schema combined form all rows and their respective values as given below.

```
Key     foo     key1        key2
1       bar     null        null
2       null    val1        val2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val data = Seq((1, """{"foo":"bar"}"""), 
             (2, """{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}"""),
             (3, """{"key1":"val1","key3":"val3", "key4": "val4"}"""))


val df = spark.createDataFrame(
  data
).toDF("num", "keyvalue")

df.show()
```

Output :

```
+---+---------------------------------------------+
|num|keyvalue                                     |
+---+---------------------------------------------+
|1  |{"foo":"bar"}                                |
|2  |{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}                |
|3  |{"key1":"val1","key3":"val3", "key4": "val4"}|
+---+---------------------------------------------+
```

Convert value in keyvalue json object to scala map object. Lets call it mapped_df

```
import scala.util.parsing.json._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

import spark.implicits._

val stringToMap = udf((str: String) => JSON.parseFull(str).get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]])

val mapped_df =df.withColumn("mapped", stringToMap(col("keyvalue")))

mapped_df.show(false)
```

Output(mapped_df) : -

```
+---+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
|num|keyvalue                                     |mapped                                    |
+---+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
|1  |{"foo":"bar"}                                |[foo -> bar]                              |
|2  |{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}                |[key1 -> val1, key2 -> val2]              |
|3  |{"key1":"val1","key3":"val3", "key4": "val4"}|[key1 -> val1, key3 -> val3, key4 -> val4]|
+---+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

Create a new data frame schema by collecting all unique key from the mapped column above

```
var schema = List(StructField("number", IntegerType))
val col_rdd = mapped_df.select(col("mapped")).rdd.map(x => {
    val maps: Map[String, String] = x.getAs[Map[String, String]]("mapped")
    val m = maps.map(x =>  x._1)
    m
})

val schem = col_rdd.flatMap(x => x).collect().sorted.toSet
val new_schema = schem.toList.map(x => StructField(x, StringType, true))
schema = schema ++ new_schema
```

Output -

```
schema: List[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField] = List(
StructField(number,IntegerType,true), 
StructField(key4,StringType,true), 
StructField(key1,StringType,true), 
StructField(key2,StringType,true), 
StructField(key3,StringType,true), 
StructField(foo,StringType,true))
```

Now that we created Schema. Convert mapped_df to rdd and do folowing operation on them so that it is consistent with our new schema:

```
val df_rdd = mapped_df.rdd.map(row => {
    val num = List(row.getAs[Int]("num"))
    val map_val: Map[String, String] = row.getAs[Map[String, String]]("mapped")
    val new_cols = schem.toList.map(x => map_val.getOrElse(x, null))
    Row.fromSeq(num ++ new_cols)
})

val new_dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(df_rdd, StructType(schema))


new_dataframe.show(false)
```

New Dtaframe vs Given Dataframe

```
New Dataframe

+------+----+----+----+----+----+
|number|key4|key1|key2|key3| foo|
+------+----+----+----+----+----+
|     1|null|null|null|null| bar|
|     2|null|val1|val2|null|null|
|     3|val4|val1|null|val3|null|
+------+----+----+----+----+----+

Given Dataframe:

+---+---------------------------------------------+
|num|keyvalue                                     |
+---+---------------------------------------------+
|1  |{"foo":"bar"}                                |
|2  |{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}                |
|3  |{"key1":"val1","key3":"val3", "key4": "val4"}|
+---+---------------------------------------------+
```

Thanks!

Comment: IT dont work if we have a nested structure like below val data = Seq((1, """{"foo":"bar"}"""), 
             (2, """{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}"""),
             (3, """{"key1":{"sub_key1":"Sub_val1"},"key3":"val3", "key4": "val4"}"""))

Comment: @Harshit In above case what would be the expected value under  key1 column in dataframe? Also would you want to create a new column callled sub_key? Could you provide expected output dataframe for above example?

Comment: Value for key is whole Map i.e. {"sub_key1":"Sub_val1"}and yes I need a new column with name sub_key1.